# Нужна ли запятая в этих случаях?

Tags: пунктуация

«Сшиб его играя»
«Побежал на него намереваясь»

Comment: *Контексту* мне, *контексту*! А то мы будем рассуждать — кабы да если бы — до морковкина заговенья.

Answer (score -1):

Одиночные деепричастия и деепричастные обороты (деепричастия + зависимые слова) выделяются запятыми независимо от того, в какой части предложения стоят. «Поспав, учитель продолжил работать». «Ученики пошли на уроки, пообедав».

Поэтому - "Сшиб его, играя" и "Побежал на него, намереваясь"

Comment: Вы цитируете текст с https://mel.fm/gramotnost/kak-pisat/365429-commas. Далее там «...Но есть деепричастия, которые выполняют роль наречия. Например: «Учитель вел уроки стоя на ногах». Здесь уже не добавочное действие, а образ действия: учитель вёл уроки как? Стоя на ногах.»